# Saving a Linux session on logout like on suspend

Tags: debian, suspend, session-restore

I'm using Debian on a PC in University and want to save my session when I log out. But saving the session should include the window position and their current content just what gets restored after suspend to RAM (stand-by) or suspend to disk (hibernate). Session managers like `lxsession` will only restart the programs that were used in the last session but not to their exact state. Is their a program that I can recommend to my sysadmin that provides extended session restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about it, each program individually would need to know how to save state. State for a word processor is different than state for a shell, is different than state for a game. Each app would need to receive a message, be told to save state, and know how/when to restart state on the new session.

Mac OSX is moving towards this, based on their experience with iOS, where you always need to suspend to "disk" based on battery life or distractions (incoming calls, etc.) It's actually a bit controversial, because its changing people's model of what a logout is on a PC.